# Netlogo How to store transfomed patches

Tags: netlogo, patch

I want to know if there is a quick way to know when a turtle is near a patch with certain characteristics and It changes it.

I have some farmers, patches with agriculture and patches protected areas. protected is a patch-own variable.

The farmer is able to transform every patch.

```
ask u-pequeños [if any? patches in-radius 20 with [pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5][ask patches in-radius 20 with [pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5] [set pcolor red]
```

However, I want them to know how many of those transformed patches are protected and store the number. I know the first part is to create a variable like transformed-protected, but how will they know the amount of patches?

Comment: isn't this just a `count patches in-radius 20 with [protected = true]` ?

Comment: But that way i just know they are there, put how would the agent know that it transformed a protected patch?

Comment: You could count all the protected patches that you know are about to be transformed right before transforming them. Or you could count untransformed protected patches before and after the transformation and taking the difference of these two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you `count` with the same condition as you used for the `ask` (`pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5`), but add another condition which is `protected = true`. If you do this right before you `ask` them to change the color, you should get the number of protected patches that are going to be transformed in the next step.

```
let transformed-protected 0
ask u-pequeños [
  if any? patches in-radius 20 with [pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5][
    set transformed-protected count patches in-radius 20 with [pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5 and protected = true]
    ask patches in-radius 20 with [pcolor = yellow and IUA > 5] [set pcolor red]
  ]
]
```